# ng-model inside radio input refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm using a jQuery library of radio/checkbox components (yeah, I know using jQuery is bad with angular, but that was not my choice to use that library and I cannot change that) and I got a problem with refreshing ng-model data (radio component in library does a simple click trigger event when radio value change).

I noticed, that while one click trigger does nothing to model, triggering it twice solves the problem (but that is not the way I would like to solve this problem). I prepared a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhBLa/)- a little example of what is my problem. First click (executing changeInput(1, 1) in the code below) on a button does a change in DOM, but does nothing to angular model - while clicking just on the radio button is doing just fine. Executing changeInput(1,2) does exacly the same as clicking the radio element.

```
function changeInput(obj, num){
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
        $('input').eq(obj).click();
    }
}
```

What else can I do? While reading stackoverflow I have noticed that people say that triggering 'input' solves the problem - but not in that case ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhBLa/1/)). Is triggering click twice is the only way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why you not use [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)?

Comment: Just as i said in question, I'm using external library of components, which executes trigger('click') on a radio change - and I need to "make it work" with my angular app.

Comment: It not really clear what constraints you have here ? What can you change and what is out of your reach ?

Comment: ExpertSystem, in this question I would like only to know how to make model changes not by triggering click twice. But in real world I suppose that I can request a pull if my add-on is something better that triggering click twice :-)

Comment: @patryk: Did you try my answer ? Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular things don't work the way you might be used to. Once you get used to it, you will enjoy the much more straightforward and declarative nature of you code.

You said:
*"in this question I would like only to know how to make model changes"*

Nevertheless, in your attempts your are trying to make model changes by changing the view (programmatically). This is both unintuitive and a nightmare in terms of maintainability.

In Angular you should worry about your data (model) and watch the views adapt automagically.

So, if you want to make model changes, then all you need to do is to...well, change the model:

```
<input type="radio" name='test' ng-model="value" value="0" />
<input type="radio" name='test' ng-model="value" value="1" />
<button ng-click="changeInput(0)">Change value to 0</button><br/>
<button ng-click="changeInput(1)">Change value to 1</button><br/>

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.value = 0;
    $scope.changeInput = function (newValue) {
        $scope.value = newValue;
    }
}
```

<sub>In order for Angular to do its magic and update the view you need to perform the action within the Angular context (`ng-click` instead of `onclick` takes care of that). If for whatever reason you can't use `ng-click`, you need to let Angular know something changed by wrapping your code in the `changeInput()` function in `$scope.apply()`.</sub>

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/N8AP8/)**.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once using only angular. The ng-binding of your input must be a property of an object defined in your controller. I think that otherwise, the input value is binded to a variable defined in the input own scope.

That wouldn't work :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected"></input>
```

But that would :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="someObject.selected"></input>
```

with for example in you controller :

```
$scope.someObject = {
 selected: false
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either: http://jsfiddle.net/zhBLa/21/ - if that is what you had in mind. Clicking button number one and three each one after another doesn't do any changes into model as expected.